# Do IBM Worklight 6.1.01 Objective C libraries support iOS 7 armv7s architecture?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use the Worklight 6.1.0.1 Objective C libraries from Objective C code to call the Worklight adapter.

I continue to get compile errors when I reference the libraries in my code and add libWorklightStaticLibProject.a to my project and compile for my iOS 7.1 iPhone5 phone (armv7s architecture).

The compiler error is: 
ld: file is universal (2 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/uname/dev/acct/cordova/platforms/ios/WorklightSDK/libWorklightStaticLibProject.a file '/Users/uname/dev/acct/cordova/platforms/ios/WorklightSDK/libWorklightStaticLibProject.a' for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have included the .a file in my list of libraries. My deployment target OS is iOS 5.1.1. Build Active Architecture (for debug) is set to YES. Valid architectures are arm64, armv7, and armv7s.

If I remove armv7s I cannot build for the current architecture (armv7s). If I build for armv7s I get this warning that the Worklight libraries do not contain a slice for the armv7s architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The armv7s architecture is not supported by IBM Worklight at this time.
This is true to all Worklight versions up to Worklight 6.1.0.x.

You can take a look at the Xcode project architecture configuration of a new app with the iPhone/iPad environment for a correct and working architecture configuration.