# IBM Worklight 6.1 Support for iOS 64-bit code

Tags: ios, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst

**Description:**

According to Apple new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support. We use worklight 6.1 (version 6.1.0.2-20150109-1528).

According to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21692883) IBM has already released IBM Worklight interim fixes to support iOS SDK 8.1 and provided a screenshot that shows the valid architectures that are supported. So when i tried to build the ios app with the suggested architectures,

[image]

i got a linker error for armv7s slice in libWorklightStaticLibProject.a.

[image]

Again according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788208/do-ibm-worklight-6-1-01-objective-c-libraries-support-ios-7-armv7s-architecture) the armv7s architecture is not supported by IBM Worklight, so i removed the armv7s from the architectures section in xcode and i rebuild with success the app.

[image: build success without armv7s arch]

**Questions**:

1. is the linker error for armv7s architecture related to 64-bit support?
2. armv7s is the architecture of the A6 processor in the iPhone 5. If i
   dont include it to avoid the error, will i have a problem with the
   app submission to appstore according to [this announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a)?
3. Does the fix that is currently installed (6.1.0.2-20150109-1528) in
   my worklight includes the fix for 64-bit support or i have to
   install another one?

Comment: I believe armv7 and arm64 are different architectures. So the issue with armv7 is not a 64 bit issue as far as I know

Answer (score 1):

Here are answer to your questions

1.Linker error for armv7s architecture is not related to 64-bit support.

2. armv7s is not related to 64 bit, its a different 32 bit arch. You will not face any issue with  app submission to appstore with respect to 64 bit announcement.
3. The iFix (6.1.0.2-20150109-1528) should include fix for 64-bit support.

I will also try test armv7s issue on 6.1.0.2-20150109-1528 build.